# Integral involving exponential of exponential convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Let $a$ and $b$ be two real numbers and $c>0$. I want to see (or compute if possible) if the following integral

$$ I = \int_0^{+\infty} y \exp(a y + b \sqrt{y} -c \exp(y)) \, dy$$

is convergent.

Comment: if $b=0$ then $G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(c\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1-a,1-a \\
 0,-a,-a \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$ is Meijer G function. If $b\neq 0$ try numerics.

Comment: How about the convergence of the integral if $b$ different from 0? Is there a way to prove convergence without the need to compute the integral?

Comment: See answer:  `Kavi Rama Murthy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $ce^{y}-b\sqrt y -ay \geq M y$ for $y$ sufficiently large, say $y>y_0$ by showing that the ratio LHS/RHS $\to \infty$. The integral from $y_0$ to $\infty$ is therefore bounded by a constant times $\int_{y_0}^{\infty} ye^{-My} dy <\infty$.